# Make types for a specific npm module global

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js, global-variables

I spend a lot of time developing discord bots, and I am always importing types when I can and using them within my code, but it would be much much handier to be able to use the types without importing them, similar to declaring global types in a d.ts file and specifying it in my tsconfig.json, but I do not want to copy the discord.js types into a global namespace. Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: I don't see any other way. Either you import the types manually, or you make them available automatically by polluting the global namespace. You say you do not "want to copy the discord.js types into a global namespace". Is this not contradicting your intention not to import them?

Comment: Personally, I don't like globals that aren't actually JavaScript globals as it pollutes the global namespace and can be confusing (e.g. `Client` would be in the global namespace and it wouldn't be immediately clear whether it's a Discord.js client or something else). If it makes it any better you could use `import type * as D from 'discord.js'` so you can refer to all Discord.js types as `D.Client` for example without having to add it to an import list like `import type {Client, Channel, Message ... } from 'discord.js'`.

Comment: My advice would be to also not over specified type information. Get comfortable with type inference and you'll find that you don't need to add extra imports for types very often.